# Smart Health Card proof of vaccination: is anyone accepting it for travel?

Tags: covid-19, vaccinations

I got my Covid shot at CVS (which is the largest pharmacy chain in the USA)
and they issued a vaccination certificate with a QR code on it. However, no regular program seems to be able to read that code. It turns out that this is a new format called Smart Health Card and it's actually a completely new URL scheme (which makes almost unreadable unless it's a very specific reader app).

Is that useful for travel at all? Do any airlines, health office, entry controls use or at least accept this as proof of vaccination?

Comment: is this US-specific? Is CVS some sort of health facility?

Comment: @KateGregory CVS is a pharmacy chain in the US

Comment: @KateGregory: My apologies. I added the context

Comment: Is it this: [SMART Health Cards](https://smarthealth.cards/)? If you read the QR-Code with a normal reader, does it start with **6BFOXN**? If yes, try installing a European checking application such as **CovPassCheck**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The spec linked from that page describes a [very different format](https://spec.smarthealth.cards/#health-cards-are-encoded-as-compact-serialization-json-web-signatures-jws) from the EU DCC. Also, even if a third party decided to issue something similar to the DCC, their signing keys would not be in the central EU gateway repository, making validation impossible.

Comment: @TooTea That is the point of the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.

Comment: Fine with me, but there are still countries that require vaccination information for entry.